# Get value outside the Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, heroku, weather-api

I want to build a web site using two API's. I've made two separate Classes for each API. I need to get 'data.currently.icon' outside `getWeather()` and class `Weather`. I was trying everything variables outside scope, getters&setters. How can I solve it?

```js
class Weather {
  constructor() {
    this.getLocation();
    this.lat;
    this.lng;
    this.icon;
  } // end constructor

  getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      this.myLocation.bind(this),
      this.errorLocation.bind(this)
    );
  }

  myLocation(result) {
    this.lat = result.coords.latitude;
    this.lng = result.coords.longitude;
    //console.log(this.lat);
    this.getWeather();
  }

  getWeather() {

    let url = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/15684c4ffc14f32fcd28af8aa81bc818/${this.lat},${this.lng}?units=si`
    fetch(url).then(response => {
      //get json 
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = data.currently.summary;
      document.querySelector('#test2').innerHTML = data.currently.temperature + "deg";
      //data.currently.icon
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  errorLocation(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

} // end class Weather
let weather = new Weather();
console.log(icon);
```

Comment: `getWeather()` is asynchronous. Even if you could access the variable, it won't be available immediately after you call `new Weather()` because the asynchronous call hasn't returned yet.

Comment: What is supposed to be the `result` param of `myLocation()`?

Comment: @DiegoSaravia result is object GeolocationPosition

Answer (score 0):

Where you wrote `//data.currently.icon` it could say

```
this.icon = data.currently.icon;
return Promise.resolve(this.icon);
```

And that last line would allow you to do the following:

```
let weather = new Weather();
weather.getWeather().then(icon => console.log(icon));
```

And you must add `return` before the `fetch(...)` so that getWeather() returns a Promise which in turn allows for `then` to be executed after the data is fetched.

Comment: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now that I think of it, getWeather() is not returning a Promise, let me think about it a little bit more

Comment: Try adding `return ` before the `fetch(url)` (and using the rest of the changes in my answer as well)

Comment: now it just 'undefined'

Comment: Are you sure that `data.currently.icon` has a value in it? If you console.log inside the `then` you should be able to see its value after the data gets fetched.

Comment: I can consol.log data.currently.icon from fetch

Comment: I created a fiddle, see if it is of any help:
https://jsfiddle.net/w3xscd5h/

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for your time and help.!

Comment: You're welcome! Can I ask you what you had to do in the end? So I can edit my answer for other people that might have the same problem

Comment: I need to compare the value of data.current.icon with my other object. If it matches I will use value of the object to get img from other API.  I need to know what weather is today(api) to display right picture(api) for this kind of weather.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my question wasn't clear, I meant what you had to do to solve the problem, so I can edit the answer correctly. I'll add now the return before the fetch expression.